# how to show railroad in openstreetmap?

Tags: android, maps, android-location, android-gps

I want to create an app that show railroad in an offline map and track location of the train in it with GPS.

Now I can only show openstreetmap data in my app in offline mode but the main question is that how can show railway in openstreetmap?

Comment: you have to get the location of train so you need internet or some sort of service which sends you the location